# Inner workings of lambda expression in C++

Tags: c++, lambda, functor

I read from a book that whenever a C++ compiler encounters a lambda expression, it internally generates a new class with overloaded `operator()`. For example, for the following lambda expression,

```
auto isOdd = [](int n){ return (n&1)==1; };
```

the compiler will create a class similar to the following.

```
class __LambdaXXX{
public:
    auto operator()(int x) const { return (n&1)==1; } 
};
```

It also said that lambda expression that does not capture any variables can be passed to a function with a function pointer because, for such lambda expression, the compiler adds nonexplicit type conversion operator to the equivalent function pointer type.

I would like to know how this conversion operator can be defined in real code. I defined a functor class and tried to pass a function object of this class to a function such as following.

```
int findFirst(const std::vector<int>& vec, bool (*predicate)(int));
```

But I could not come up with a correct solution. I tried to define a conversion operator in the functor class. I also tried to typecast a pointer to a member function to a function pointer without any success.

I know if I use a `std::function<>` template instead of function pointer, I can pass a function pointer, a functor, and a lambda expression without needing any conversion but I am very curious how a compiler adds conversion operator that allows a functor to be passed to a function pointer.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an issue with your conversion operator, you should show the code. However, the thing is that you need a function first before you can get a pointer to it. One possibility is to use a static method:

```
#include <iostream>


struct LambdaXXX{
public:
    auto operator()(int x) const { call(x); } 
    using f_ptr = bool(*)(int);
    operator f_ptr() const noexcept {
        return &LambdaXXX::call;
    }
private:
    static bool call(int x) {
        return (x&1)==1;
    }
};

void f( bool(*F)(int)) {
    std::cout << F(42);
}


int main() 
{
    auto lam = LambdaXXX{};
    f(lam);
}
```

I admit, I don't know if this is how lambdas actually do it. Note that it is just [specified as](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> The value returned by this conversion function is a pointer to a function with C++ language linkage that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure object's function call operator directly.

How it is implemented is left to the implementation.

Comment: If the arguments were classes, you'd need to copy/move them to forward to the static function. I wonder if it's possible to avoid it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat a trivial fix is to duplicate implementation in `call` and `operator()`

Comment: And here we can also ask why an overloaded operator of a empty class can not be static...  in this case we can directly give the pointer to that function... As we have no technical problem making the operator static "magically", it is a possibility  what implementations do internally for captureless lambdas